# Communication of Deep Learning models with Protobuf and grpc: analysing the overhead

Tags: ssl, deep-learning, pytorch, protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose you have 2 different Deep Learning models, such as ResNet-18 and MobileNet-V3 small. Below you can see the number of parameters, the total size in megabytes and the number of layers of both models:

| Model | Parameters | Size (MB) | Layers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ResNet-18 | 11.175.370 | 42.67 | 68 |
| MobileNet-V3 Small | 1.527.818 | 5.88 | 210 |

The DL framework considered is PyTorch.
Now, considering that the MB size of ResNet is about 6 times bigger than the size of MobileNet, and the total number of trainable parameters of ResNet is 9 times the number of those of MobileNet, I think that when I have to send this model through one machine to another one, then the communication time of ResNet will be greater than the time required to send MobileNet.
However, my empirical considerations show that the time necessary to send MobileNet (20 seconds) is more or less double of the one to send ResNet (10 seconds).
The framework that I adopted uses Protobuf, grpc and TLS to serialize and communicate. I have zero knowledge of both of these technologies. The only thing that I noted is bigger in MobileNet is the number of layers. Indeed MobileNet has around 3 times the number of layers of ResNet (210 vs 68).  However, a lot of these layers are ReLU and AvgPool, so they do not contain trainable parameters.
Do you know if the number of layers can influence so much the time requested to send a deep learning model?